# Tag max(sum) of row in a numpy array to a list element using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, matrix

To keep it simple, I am listing out in numbered form

1) I have a list with filenames

2) I would like to extract a record from numpy array which has a maximum row-wise sum higher when compared to other records(rows)

Please find the screenshot below for reference

What I have done is created an array and found out the sum using np.sum function. However, I am not able to find a method to extract the row based on this sum condition. I would like to have only the specific row and sum value which can be tagged to an element in list. Is there any elegant python function to do this?

```
t1 = ['abc_1.png','abc_2.png'] -- list with filenames as elements
arr_1 = np.random.rand(3,3)    -- array 1
arr_2 = np.random.rand(3,3)    -- array 2
arr1_sum = np.sum(arr_1,axis=1)
arr2_sum = np.sum(arr_2,axis=1)        -- the last two statement returns an array. I would like to extract the corresponding row/record which contributes to that sum and tag it to the first and second element in list (abc_1.png)
```

The expected output can be in either list or dictionary form. Please find the sample screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this iteratively for a list of files and arrays, you could:

```
files = ['abc_1.png','abc_2.png']

arr_1 = np.random.rand(3,3)
arr_2 = np.random.rand(3,3)

arrays = [arr_1, arr_2]

sums = [np.sum(arr, axis=1) for arr in arrays]

output_dict = {}

for i in range(len(files)):
    max_index = int(np.where(sums[i] == max(sums[i]))[0])
    output_dict[files[i]] = arrays[i][max_index]
```

And like @warped said, you could use np.argmax() to forego the for loop:

```
files = ['abc_1.png','abc_2.png']

arr_1 = np.random.rand(3,3)
arr_2 = np.random.rand(3,3)

arrays = [arr_1, arr_2]

sums = [np.sum(arr, axis=1) for arr in arrays]

output_dict = {files[i]: list(arrays[i][np.argmax(sums[i]), :]) for i in range(len(files))}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for [np.argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
max_row = arr_2[np.argmax(arr2_sum), :]

output = list(max_row)
output.append(np.max(arr2_sum))

output = {'abc_2.png' : output}
```